# Selenium Java - how do I run only one test?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I am currently using Java and Selenium and I have over 50 tests in just one class. Is there an easier way to run only one test, other than putting @Ignore on every other test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse you can do following:

1. go to your class file (source code)
2. right click on your testing method name
3. click "Run As.."
4. click "Run Junit Test"

it will run the one that you want to test

Comment: Every IDE I know have an option like that.

Comment: so You want to run it by programming?